# Executable Resolution for exec.Command + PATH

Tags: shell, go, path, environment-variables

Having pretty similar command calls

```
cmdDirect := exec.Command("theExecutable")
cmdShell := exec.Command(os.GetEnv("SHELL"),  "-c",  "theExecutable")
```

both have the same Env setup

```
envWithPath := append(os.Environ(), fmt.Sprintf("PATH=/real/existing/path/to/theExecutable/holder:%s", os.GetEnv("PATH")))

cmdDirect.Env = envWithPath
cmdShell.Env = envWithPath
```

Still while `cmdShell` works well as expected the `cmdDirect` fails with

```
exec: "theExecutable": executable file not found in $PATH
```

For the very same mentioned environment setup the call is successful as well for

```
cmdWhich := exec.Command("which", "theExecutable")
```

with return properly `/real/existing/path/to/theExecutable/holder/theExecutable`

So what could be the reason for such a difference?

P.S. as well both approaches for sure have the very same `$PATH` setup. E.g.

```
exec.Command("env")
exec.Command(os.GetEnv("SHELL"),  "-c",  "env")
```

are both outputs the same `PATH=....` sequence

Thx

Comment: The shell you are using can load a different environment from what your current process has. `echo $PATH` from within that same shell and see what it is.

Comment: @JimB `PATH`s are totally identical. Added info to the question

Comment: what is that `cmd*.Env = append(` line supposed to be doing? Aside from the invalid syntax, it's not modifying the `PATH` variable, it's adding a new variable named after the executable path.

Comment: @JimB Oh `cmd*` it was just a pseudo code wildcard (i.e. both for  `Direct` and `Shell` suffixes). For the `PATH=` format sorry it was a mistyped in the question it self (fixed), original code is valid -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec.Command` finds the path for the executable with `exec.LookPath` which uses your PATH, not the one set on the cmd.

I would recommend setting `Cmd.Path` to the path to the executable if you would like more reliable lookups to specific executables (or spawn a sub-shell as you have).

Comment: Ahhh!! Great. thanks. The behavior is pretty respected to what you've  described. Is there any shortcut for `exec.Command(os.GetEnv("SHELL"),  "-c",  "command with args")` that would additionally serialize/unquote/escape the args slice under the hood for that? As I understand the `Cmd.Path` it self is not the same as "PATH" and should contain only one final destination path isn't it? Or can I resolve it on the fly having customized "PATH" value. I can't see the way to provide it to `exec.LookPath` explicitly.

Comment: Or would be `os.GetEnv("SHELL"),  "-c"` combination really enough `cross shell`ish for general call?

Comment: yeah, if you do `cmd, _ := exec.Command("theExecutable")` you should be able to inspect the value of `cmd.Path` and it will be an absolute path to the executable you are trying to invoke. If it's not what you expect it to be, you can set it to something else.

I agree there is not a way to control the PATH being accessed in `exec.LookPath` and I would maybe consider populating the Cmd by hand if you want very granular control over what is run.